# Why doesn't every ring have a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Hello I'm reading the proof for *Theorem 7* [here](https://osebje.famnit.upr.si/%7Eruss.woodroofe/wustl-notes/zorn.pdf) and I'm struggling to grasp at which point it's necessary that the ring be commutative.
I tried looking elsewhere and through other posts here but am still at loss. Help is appreciated.

Comment: At no point does the linked document suggest that the result only holds for commutative rings. Clearly this is part of a course about commutative rings, and therefore the result is stated in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In non-commutative case we have three distinct notions of ideals: left ideals, right ideals and two-sided ideals. They all coincide in commutative rings, but not necessarily in non-commutative case.

With that we have:

> [**Krull's theorem.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_theorem) For every unital ring $R$ and a proper left/right/two-sided ideal $I\subseteq R$ there is a proper maximal left/right/two-sided ideal $M\subseteq R$ containing $I$.

The standard proof is by applying the Zorn's lemma to the collection $$\{J\subseteq R\ |\ J\text{ is a proper ideal containing }I\}$$ and indeed it doesn't depend on commutativity at all. The main observation is that a left/right/two-sided ideal $J\subseteq R$ is proper if and only if $1\in J$. And therefore union of a chain of proper ideals is again proper.

Note that the theorem is not true for non-unital rings, even when commutative. Indeed, given any abelian group $A$ we can turn it into a non-unital commutative ring by setting $g\cdot h:=0$. Then ideals correspond to subgroups, and we all know that abelian groups don't have to have maximal subgroups (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$). And so the multiplicative unity plays very important role here, unlike commutativity.

Anyway, for unital rings the assumption is superfluous. I suppose that the author (of the paper you read) simply deals with commutative rings only.